# What is this yellow flowering mounded plant?

Tags: identification, flowers

I saw this flower while walking outside and would be really interested in growing it in my garden. Can anyone tell me what it's called?

[image]

Comment: Please ask a separate question for each plant you want to identify. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site Artur. We're glad you found us! It's easier for people to help you if we know where your plant is located. Would you please edit that into your question? If you have any trouble, leave a note here and someone will help you! Also, if you haven't already, check out our [Help Center](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Genista - as to which, that's the difficulty, deciding which one it is. Could be a Genista tricuspidata cultivar, Genista 'Porlock' or Genista tinctoria 'flore pleno' - there's a host of cultivars for this plant. Different varieties vary in height and spread between 0.5 metres up to 8 metres high and wide (genista aetnensis), though the most popular are the smaller cultivars - there are some with orange or reddish yellow flowers.  All flower in spring, with maybe a few flowers in autumn if you're lucky, and all prefer light, not too fertile soil that's free draining, and full sun.

Comment: They flower in spring if rabbits have not eaten them...sigh, what a hard winter will do..